# I get a forcestop occasionally when I press buttons other than the first

Tags: android

I have 3 buttons in total. And it seemed that, if I don't press the first button, and instead second or third button right after I startup, my application will forcestop.

My code for part1 : http://pastebin.com/udkEdF3E

```
package project.ernest;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class Part1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


      final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Disclaimer); 
      a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) { 
            Intent b = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part2.class);         
            Part1.this.startActivity(b); 


      final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Orientation); 
      c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            Intent d = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part3.class);         
            Part1.this.startActivity(d);


      final Button e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Course); 
      e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            Intent f = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part4.class);         
            Part1.this.startActivity(f);
        }
      });
      };
        });
      };
            });
      };
    }
```

my code for main.xml : http://pastebin.com/SxfxfJ4a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/myColor" android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="404dp">
        <TextView android:text="@string/HospName" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textSize="20mm" android:layout_width="324dp" android:layout_height="142dp"></TextView>
        <Button android:text="@string/Disclaimer" android:layout_weight="0.37" android:textSize="5mm" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/Disclaimer" android:drawingCacheQuality="high" android:onClick="@string/DisclaimerHandler"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@string/Orientation" android:textSize="5mm" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_weight="0.37" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/Orientation" android:onClick="@string/OrientationHandler"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@string/Course" android:textSize="5mm" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_weight="0.37" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/Course" android:onClick="@string/CourseHandler"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.19" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:weightSum="1">
        <Button android:layout_weight="0.23" android:text="@string/Search" android:textSize="1.9mm" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_width="75dp" android:onClick="@string/SearchHandler" android:id="@+id/Search"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_weight="0.23" android:text="@string/Contact" android:textSize="1.9mm" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_width="75dp" android:onClick="@string/ContactHandler" android:id="@+id/Contact"></Button>
        <Button android:onClick="@string/LinkHandler" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_weight="0.23" android:textSize="1.9mm" android:text="@string/Link" android:id="@+id/Link"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_weight="0.23" android:text="@string/Copyright" android:textSize="1.9mm" android:layout_height="75dp" android:layout_width="75dp" android:onClick="@string/CopyrightHandler" android:id="@+id/Copyright"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The error I get is either:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method CourseHandler(View) in activity class project.ernest.Part1 or...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method OrientationHandler(View) in activity class project.ernest.Part1 or...
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the format.

```
public class Part1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


  final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Disclaimer); 
  a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) { 
        Intent b = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part2.class);         
        Part1.this.startActivity(b); 
      }
  });


  final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Orientation); 
  c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        Intent d = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part3.class);         
        Part1.this.startActivity(d);
   }
  });

  final Button e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Course); 
  e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        Intent f = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part4.class);         
        Part1.this.startActivity(f);
      }
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: @user990571: But do you actually understand what you did wrong in your source? And how to avoid it in the future?

Comment: yup, cause my code was only listening to one button instead of 3. therefore, when it wasn't listening to the second and third button, and i press it, it will occur an error.

Answer (score 3):

You've placed initialization of buttons 2 and 3 inside the first button's `onClickListener()`, means they won't be initialized before you click the first button. Fix your code.

Comment: any that you will recommend to change?

Comment: To make matters worse, initialisation of the third button is also inside the `onClickListener()` of the second button. OP: Fix you indentation, then you will see the problem clearly!

Comment: @user990571, I'd recommend you to stop coding and start reading literature. Sorry if I hurt you, but you make rather silly mistakes, that makes me think that you're not ready to program yet. Learn!